# How to access global variables that are non-functions? Python

Tags: python, function, variables, global, isinstance

**How to access global variables that are non-functions?**

Currently I'm access `globals()` and then manually hardcoding the deletion of functions that I know exist in the module, i.e.

```
x, y, z = 1, 2, 3

def f(i, j):
    return i+j

def g():
   variables = globals()
   del variables['g']
   del variables['f']
```

**Could this be done automatically? (Assume that I don't know what the types of variables there are except that they should not be functions?**

It'll be rather strange if i am to loop through the `globals()` and i try to remove it within the loop:

```
>>> import types
>>> x, y, z = 1,2,3
>>> def g():
...     variables = globals()
...     for k in variables:
...             if isinstance(variables[k], types.FunctionType):
...                     del variables[k]
... 
>>> g()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in g
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I've to do something like:

```
>>> def g():
...     variables = globals()
...     functions = []
...     for k in variables:
...             if isinstance(variables[k], types.FunctionType):
...                     functions.append(k)
...     for f in functions:
...             del variables[f]
... 
>>> g()
```

Is there a simpler way to access global variables that are non-functions?

---

## EDITED

```
>>> x, y, z = 1,2,3
>>> def f(i,j):
...     return i+j
... 
>>> globals()
{'f': <function f at 0x105f6df50>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, '__name__': '__main__', 'z': 3, '__doc__': None}
>>> def g():
...     print globals()
... 
>>> g()
{'g': <function g at 0x105f72320>, 'f': <function f at 0x105f6df50>, '__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, '__name__': '__main__', 'z': 3, '__doc__': None}
```

Comment: Why are you using global variables at all?

Comment: it's for an use case where there are lots of global variables that should be accessed by multiple functions.

Comment: **Never modify a data structure while looping through it** This will screw up your data structure and return you the dictionary size change error. If you **really** want to do it, your second way of doing it works.

Comment: Why not use a dict from the start instead of using all these global variables?

Comment: Try using clone of `variables` in the for loop: `for k in dict(variables):`.

Comment: Could you explain what is the `dict` you're referring to? The `globals()` returns a dict but the values of these dict could be itself a function, in the question, it would be `g()` itself. See updated question.